# How to load an external property file to Spring Boot in Wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I wonder how can I load an external property of my application running inside Wildfly 9 as WAR, I tried to add a java parameter to Wildfly execution but it seems the application did not recognize the properties.

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:///C:\Temp\config\application.properties,classpath:application.properties
```

Is there any way how Spring Boot could read the external property file? I am trying to load and run one Spring Boot application as WAR inside Wildfly.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my linux system i have an entry in the **standalone.xml**:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="spring.config.location" value="file:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/"/>
</system-properties>
```

I just defined the directory here, so it has to end with an "/".

In the directory "*/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/*" there is my application.yml.

Comment: To avoid to set specific path, you can use the built in Wildfly configuration path variable as follow:
`<property name="spring.config.location" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/" />`

Answer (score 0):

If your springboot application is running inside Wildfly you don't need to read standalone.xml as an external file.

Get the property value directly with System.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late for the answer, but maybe this helps:

- Within your deployment-descriptor (web.xml), create environment-variables pointing to the spring config location file, i.e.

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
        <env-entry>
            <env-entry-name>spring.config.location</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>file:[path-to-file]/[your-properties-file] 
  </env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
    </web-app>
  ```

Working on Wildfly 25.0.0